# Binets second loggamma formula

Tags: integration, alternative-proof, gamma-function

Binets second loggamma formula states that the error term for stirlings approximation of the loggamma function is $2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{arctan(u/z) }{e^{2\pi u}-1}~\mathrm du$. I remember being able to derive this from the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula, but was wondering if there’s an easier way to show this? I tried using the Abel Plana formula but I don’t think the loggamma formula satisfies the bounds necessary for use. What’s an alternative proof?

Answer (score 1):

The [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) is applicable to $f(x)=1/(x+z)^2$ with $\Re z>0$, giving $$\big(\ln\Gamma(z)\big)''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+z)^2}=\frac{1}{2z^2}+\frac{1}{z}+\int_0^\infty\frac{4zx\ dx}{(z^2+x^2)^2(e^{2\pi x}-1)}.$$ This can be integrated twice, using the main asymptotics to determine the integration constants.

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of using f(n)=x/(n+1)-ln(1+x/(n+1)). I also found that you can use f(u)=1/(u+x)